# What equation could I use for a graph similar to a damped sine graph, but whose local minimum changes at a different rate to its local maximum?

Tags: graphing-functions

[graph in question, graphed on desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMuqI.png)

This graph represents the height of a yo-yo over time. I have been struggling to find a generic equation resembling this line shape. Is there an equation out there that, when graphed, would look something like this?

Comment: A natural model would be a sequence of parabola of exponentially decreasing height. Same as a bouncing ball that loses a portion of its energy each time it hits the ground.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of $e^{-\frac{x}{4}} \cos(x) + e^{-\frac{x}{4}} \sin(x)$ ?